# Should "debt-collectors" and "debt-collection" tags be combined?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed today that we have both [debt-collectors](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt-collectors) and [debt-collection](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt-collection) tags that seem identical.

[debt-collectors](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt-collectors) has 19 questions.  It has no tag excerpt.

[debt-collection](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt-collection) has 35 questions.  The tag excerpt currently says, "For questions related to debt collection, debt collection agencies, unpaid debts, etc."

Some of these questions have both tags.

Should these tags be combined?  If so, which one should remain, and which one should be the synonym?

Comment: And if you like this question, [check this one out](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/q/325/10997).  :)

Comment: I was just about to ask this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the tags should be combined.  One tag for this subject is enough.

My personal preference is that the [debt-collection](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt-collection) tag be kept.  [debt-collectors](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt-collectors) should be made a tag synonym.

Comment: No dissent, seems like an obvious one; I've implemented this now.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a "collection" tag alongside "debt-collection". Could these too be merged?

I presume "collections" is separate and means "collectables"...?